# Image Overlay "margin-top" does not show correctly with differing image heights

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, margin

the issue is best visible in the fiddle [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndb9sugf/)

The image overlay is set to margin-top: -100%; but it doesnt work for items, who are longer then 300x300.

ive tried to use jquery as follows:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $(".overlay").each(function () {
            var $parentHeight = $(".overlay").parent().height();

            $(".overlay").css("margin-top", -$parentHeight);
        });
    });
```

That had the same outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use top:0 not margin-top:-100%;

```
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s all;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

I did this edit on your style see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/ngmpm5x0/